# Function Unit Test sending multipart/form-data to a Mule flow

Tags: mule

I am using JMeter to send Multipart Messages like this:

```
Raw Post body
Body

Send files with the request
    path          Parameter Name    Mime type
    file1.jmx     Payload           multipart/form-data
    test.jpg      Attachment
```

However we would like to move this over to a Function Unit Test. Is there a best practice way to do this in Mule? Do I just send a mule message with attachments? Would this be a good replication of a http Multipart message?

```
msg.addAttachment(name, dataHandler)
MuleMessage result = client.send("http://localhost:8090/", msg, 200 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of tests, I like to use Apache's [Common HTTP Client](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) because it is independent of Mule (so it simulates a "neutral" HTTP client) and it's easy to use from a functional test method.

Comment: ah the useful commons to the rescue, nice one!

Comment: Also use a dynamic port in your functional tests to prevent any conflict and random failures.

Comment: It tries to bind a server socket to it: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/core/src/test/java/org/mule/tck/PortUtils.java#L83